# I am trying to create custom user registration form

Tags: django

I am getting this error.Below mentioned code is for forms.py

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from dappx.models import UserProfileInfo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['username','password','email']


class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = UserProfileInfo
      fields = ['portfolio_site','profile_pic']
```

Comment: Where is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    Form class to register a new user
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','password','email']
```

I found [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) a good reading source